# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again with Itext7

Tags: itext7

When I tried update PDF file using Itext7, getting error "Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again"

My Code:

```java
String src="pdf1.pdf";

String dest="pdf1.pdf";
   
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(src), new PdfWriter(dest));
Document document = new Document(pdfDoc);
   
//Create canvas from the last page
PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(pdfDoc.addNewPage());
   
canvas.beginText().setFontAndSize(
        PdfFontFactory.createFont(FontConstants.HELVETICA), 12)
            .moveText(265, 597)
            .showText("I agree to the terms and conditions.")
            .endText();
   
document.close()
```

[image]

Comment: That is certainly not a problem with iText. Please try to minimize your code, try a different JVM and identify where is the edge where the problem stops to be reproducible

Comment: It is working fine if I save it different  file.

Comment: If you open your document with a reader and a writer, the files must be different. It's not possible to manipulate a file in-place. The JVM shouldn't have crashed anyway though